# Why Vapor / Droplet does not receive JSON?

Tags: json, vapor, droplet

Sending a JSON to local service, but it does not receive it, why?

```
let config = try Config()
try config.setup()

let drop = try Droplet(config)
try drop.setup()

drop.get(handler: {req in

    if req.json != nil {

        print("ass")
        print(req.json!)
    }

    return "almaG"
})
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a GET request with a body. Try sending a POST instead and use drop.post().

Comment: Works, now `req.body` delivers info, but why not `req.json`?

Comment: You probably need a "Content-Type: application/json" header.

Comment: Nope, it does not help.